# How to pass a value to the UserControl (uwp)

Tags: c#, user-controls, uwp, uwp-xaml

How to pass a value to the UserControl (uwp)

```
<Pivot Title="Welcome" Name="View_P" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" >
    <PivotItem Header="Car" Name="v_1">
        <local:View_Control />
            </PivotItem>

            <PivotItem Header="electronics">
        <local:View_Control/>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

See in PivotItem0 and PivotItem0

```
<local:View_Control/>
```

next code c#

```
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if( View_P.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        View_Control.numbers=1
    }
    else if (View_P.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        View_Control.numbers = 2
    }
}
```

next code UserControl Name page (View_Control)

```
public  int numbers;
public View_Control()
{
    ServiceErkaanClient dv = new ServiceErkaanClient();
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyGrid1.ItemsSource = dv.SP_All_SellAsync(numbers).Result;
}
```

Required
If click Pivot SelectedIndex == 0 sends a parameter to UserControl (View_Control) 1 and Refresh

Comment: I think your Pivot_SelectionChanged method may wrong.

Comment: The first you should give the name to your control and you should change the number to property. The second is you should update when number be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first, you should set name to View_Control and you can see the code below.

```
<Pivot Title="Welcome" Name="View_P" 
       SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" >
    <PivotItem Header="Car" Name="v_1">
         <local:View_Control Name="v1"/>
    </PivotItem>

    <PivotItem Header="electronics">
        <local:View_Control Name="v2"/>
    </PivotItem>
 </Pivot>
```

The second is change filed number to property and you can see the code below.

```
    private int _numbers;
    public int Numbers
    {
        set
        {
            _numbers=value;

            //when the numbers be changed

            ServiceErkaanClient dv = new ServiceErkaanClient();
            MyGrid1.ItemsSource = dv.SP_All_SellAsync(numbers).Result;
        }
        get
        {
            return _numbers;
        }
    }
    public View_Control()
    {
        ServiceErkaanClient dv = new ServiceErkaanClient();
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyGrid1.ItemsSource = dv.SP_All_SellAsync(Numbers).Result;
    }
```

When you set the number to 1 ,that it will call SP_All_SellAsync.

If you want use dependency property, you can try the below code

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty NumbersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Numbers", typeof(int), typeof(View_Control), new PropertyMetadata(default(int), (s, e) =>
        {
            View_Control view = (View_Control) s;
            int n = (int) e.NewValue;

            ServiceErkaanClient dv = new ServiceErkaanClient();
            view.MyGrid1.ItemsSource = dv.SP_All_SellAsync(n).Result;
        }));

    public int Numbers
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(NumbersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumbersProperty, value); }
    }

    public View_Control()
    {
        ServiceErkaanClient dv = new ServiceErkaanClient();
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyGrid1.ItemsSource = dv.SP_All_SellAsync(Numbers).Result;
    }
```

Welcome to communicate with me，if you have any questions.

Comment: change `Numbers` to a Dependency Properties

Comment: @VijayNirmal I did not see him using bindings

Comment: <local:View_Control Numbers="1"  x:Name="v1"/>

 please update you code

Comment: @Abdullah Is your numbers default is one?